# React Redux - Keep the same URL while navigating to different pages

Tags: reactjs, redux

We're using React with Redux and redux-simple-router for navigations. I'm building a 2 page form and would like to keep the URL to same between the 2 pages. Pressing the back button on the browser currently will navigate from page 2 to page 1. We'd like to keep this functionality with any solution.

Is this possible using react, redux and redux-simple-router and how would you achieve it?

Comment: Without anything that uniquely identifies the two different stages of the form, normally through the URL `/the-form?step=2` it'd be impossible to implement this unless by browsing `/the-form` you'd always go to step 1.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [winterfell](https://github.com/andrewhathaway/Winterfell) this might be what you are looking for. This library doesn't specifically handle storing the data in a redux store but you could structure you store something like this:

```
{
  currentPage: 2,
  form: {
    page1: {
      field1: '',
      field2: ''
    },
    page2: {
      field3: ''
    }
  }  
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The example looks good however we have a requirement of going back to the previous back on the browser 'back' button. This is already taken care of by redux-simple-router and so we'd like to keep that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not using `redux-simple-router`. If you keyed the differences between your pages to data in your state, you could use regular actions to affect the transitions between your pages, and the URL wouldn't be affected.

Comment: Hi Acjay, a requirement that I had forgotten to mention was the ability to go back to the previous page on browser back. I don't believe keeping state in the store would achieve this?

Comment: @n00b According to the [`pushState` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState), this may actually be possible, but I don't know much more than that.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something similar to the [react-router shared root example.](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/examples/auth-with-shared-root/config/routes.js#L67) Store the current "page" in a reducer and then dynamically load the container component based on page.

Might be better to just use two routes or store the state at the component level and create a parent container to handle the showing of the two forms based on the stored state.

Comment: Would this allow intercepting the browser back action in order to navigate to the previous page?